# C# Reflection not Working 100%

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a program with a Managed Executable as a resource,
when I try to load the exe using reflection with the following code:

```
byte[] file = Properties.Resources.ExeName;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(file);
// search for the Entry Point
MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;
if (method != null)
{
    // create an instance of the Startup form Main method
    object handle = assembly.CreateInstance(method.Name);
    // invoke the application starting point
    method.Invoke(handle, null);
}
```

The assembly I try to load is a valid Managed assembly compiled against .NET Framework 2.0 having the following instruction:

```
MessageBox.Show("Some Text");
//other stuff goes here
```

The problem is when I run the application I don't get any `MessageBox.Show ("Message")` dialog, I tried putting breakpoints in the code everything works fine until it reaches the instruction:

```
method.Invoke(handle, null);
```

Once I Step Over here, nothing happens, it neither give any error or exception not it freezes the Editor (VS 2017 Community Edition).

I tried loading other Managed Assemblies, it works fine (provided the assemblies are complied against the same .NET Framework Version (2.0)).

Can anyone point out what possible could be the reason why is the desired exe not executed as expected.

Comment: The size alone should not have anything to do with it. We have multi-megabyte assemblies at work and reflection works just fine. In any case, posts with content like "why is my code not working" must post some code. Also, are you sure those 300KB files are actually .NET assemblies? Do you have try/catch statements with empty catch blocks in your program?

Comment: Executable size has nothing to do with anything. It's unclear what *loading exe using reflection* is supposed to mean. What **specifically** are you trying to do? Are you certain all of the executables you're *loading* (whatever that means) are managed .NET executables? Reflection doesn't work on native applications.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , yes the files are .NET assemblies , thanks for your comment

Comment: @KenWhite "loading exe using reflection" mean i have managed assemblies with valid entryPoints i use Assembly.Load(sourceBytes) , i put break points in the code everything looks good except for the output , i have uploaded some code , you might be interested in

Comment: what do you mean by "except for the output"? there is no output in your code. did you debug? what happened? does the loading hang? no entry point? and after that, if the entry point method does get called, the rest depends on that assembly, which we don't know....Maybe it's waiting for input.

Comment: @RenéVogt the Assembly i try to load have an MessageBox.Show("Some Text") , it doesn't show anything , it doesnt need any input but Debugging stops at "  methodInfo.Invoke(handle, null );"

Comment: Size can't be the factor, so start writing that [mcve] and find out which feature/difference triggers this. We can't look in your PC or your files.

Comment: You can't create an instance of a method, if the method is not static you must create an instance of its declaring type. This part of your code is wrong, for all assemblies. Are you sure this is the real code you're using? Does it work at all? Are you sure CreateInstance returns something and not just `null`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen are you sure this code wont work at all ? if yes ,  in that case you better give it a try

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for the link , i have reworded the question

Comment: .NET has two MessageBox classes, neither has a `Show(/*no params*/)` method.

Comment: _"... other Managed Assemblies , it works fine "_ - and what code was in there?

Comment: @Constantine It "works" if `Assembly.CreateInstance` returns `null` when given an invalid name, because you cannot create an instance of a method, only of a type, and if it returns `null`, then it works because the entry point is static and thus you need to pass `null` for the invoke instance parameter, but you could just as easily do `methodInfo.Invoke(null, ...)`

Comment: In any case, my observations does not tell you why it fails to load your other assemblies.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , the other working assemblies contain a console messages Console.WriteLine("Some Text");

Comment: So it turns out that this has nothing to do with Reflection but just "how to show a MsgBox from a Console App". Google that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, no its not the case,  thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

[`Assembly.EntryPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint(v=vs.110).aspx) is the method that is the entry point for an assembly which will be, even in a Windows Forms project be the `Main` method. Because this is returning a method, you cannot call [`Assembly.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) on it as this is used to create an instance of a Type (which in the case of the `Main` method is probably called `Namespace.For.Project.`**`Program`**.

You also need to ensure that you're passing the correct number of parameters to the method you're calling, in the second parameter to the call to `method.Invoke`. In a simple console application, the `Main` method has a signature of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
```

This means that you need to pass one parameter in, an array of strings. Putting this all together you get:

```
byte[] file = Properties.Resources.ExeName;

Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(file);
// search for the Entry Point
MethodInfo method = assembly.EntryPoint;

if (method != null)
{
    // Get the type that implements the EntryPoint method
    var implementingType = method.DeclaringType;
    // Call the EntryPoint method, passing in an empty array of strings as its parameters
    method.Invoke(implementingType, new object[] { new string[] { } });
}
```

When I've created the assembly that is referenced by `Properties.Resources.Exename` as a "simple" console application (targeting .net Framework 2.0) with the following for the `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message " + args == null ? "NULL" : "NOT NULL " + args.Length);
}
```

Running the program pops a message box with the text "NOT NULL 0" in it, indicating that the parameter has been passed through and is an empty array, which is what I was expecting to see.